# Create columns of a unique value of a column and get their counts in SQL

Tags: sql

Say I have a table like this:

[image]

In SQL, I want to create columns of the unique values of the Fruit field and get their counts for each ID. For example:

[image]

How would I do this?

Comment: This is called a `PIVOT` (which is hard to search for if you don't know the word). Search up `PIVOT` and the name of the RDBMS you are using (sql server, oracle, mysql, mariadb, postgres, snowflake, teradata, azure, sqlite, MSAccess, etc) and you'll find a whole treasure trove of info. To have any hope of getting an answer here, please edit the question and include the name of the RDBMS you are using in the tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a couple of different ways. I've included your examples as test data that I put into temporary tables.
In the first example, I use Group By and then add up all the instances where the case results in 1.
In the second example, I get all the unique values for the IDs and then use Partition By which is the same as a group by (but only for that single measurement). And then it adds up the 1's just like in the first version.
Version 1:

```
Declare @TestData TABLE
(
  ID      char(1),
  Fruit   varchar(6)
);

INSERT INTO @TestData (ID, Fruit) select 'A', 'Apple'
INSERT INTO @TestData (ID, Fruit) select 'A', 'Apple'
INSERT INTO @TestData (ID, Fruit) select 'A', 'Orange'
INSERT INTO @TestData (ID, Fruit) select 'B', 'Apple'
INSERT INTO @TestData (ID, Fruit) select 'B', 'Grape'
INSERT INTO @TestData (ID, Fruit) select 'B', 'Grape'

select t1.ID,
      sum(case when t1.Fruit like 'Apple' then 1 else 0 end) as '_Apple',
      sum(case when t1.Fruit like 'Orange' then 1 else 0 end) as '_Orange',
      sum(case when t1.Fruit like 'Grape' then 1 else 0 end) as '_Grape'

from  @TestData  as t1
group by t1.ID
```

Version 2

```
Declare @TestData TABLE
(
  ID      char(1),
  Fruit   varchar(6)
);

INSERT INTO @TestData (ID, Fruit) select 'A', 'Apple'
INSERT INTO @TestData (ID, Fruit) select 'A', 'Apple'
INSERT INTO @TestData (ID, Fruit) select 'A', 'Orange'
INSERT INTO @TestData (ID, Fruit) select 'B', 'Apple'
INSERT INTO @TestData (ID, Fruit) select 'B', 'Grape'
INSERT INTO @TestData (ID, Fruit) select 'B', 'Grape'

select distinct t1.ID,
      sum(case when t1.Fruit like 'Apple' then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by t1.ID ) as '_Apple',
      sum(case when t1.Fruit like 'Orange' then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by t1.ID) as '_Orange',
      sum(case when t1.Fruit like 'Grape' then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by t1.ID) as '_Grape'
from  @TestData  as t1
```